# Prove that these two fields are isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> I want to prove that $\bar{K}[V]/M_p \simeq \bar{K}$ where $K$ is a field, $\bar{K}$ is its algebraic closure and
>   $$\bar{K}[V]=\bar{K}[x_1,...,x_n]/I_V,$$
>   where $I_V$ is the ideal attached to a variety, so it is prime.

Now, on the other hand:

$$M_p=\{f \in \bar{K}[V] : f(p)=0\}.$$

So we have to find a bijective function from this two fields (may be there are better ways to do this, but I am not quite sure if in field theory we can find that machinery), but my intuition says that in $\bar{K}[V]/M_p$ we don't have any vanishing polynomial at $V$ so I can't figure out how to find this bijection.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Firstly $\tilde{K}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ is not a field. Secondly you define $\tilde{K}[V]$ as a quotient of $\tilde{K}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$, and then take its quotient by another ideal of $\tilde{K}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well the ideal is prime :),can you clarify please ? :)

Comment: I think you may have some typos in your question then :) See my first comment.

Comment: let me check :) so I can be sure just a second

Comment: I've edited :) is it clear now?

Comment: I know it is a little bit weird to have those quotients but I've got it like that :(

Comment: No can you elaborate please ?

Comment: So then :) what can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$, then $M_P=(x_1-a_1,\dots,x_n-a_n)/I(V)$; see [Proving that kernels of evaluation maps are generated by the $x_i - a_i$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500153/proving-that-kernels-of-evaluation-maps-are-generated-by-the-x-i-a-i) (the proof given there works for any field).

Then $\overline K[V]/M_P\simeq\overline K[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(x_1-a_1,\dots,x_n-a_n)\simeq\overline K$; for the last isomorphism see [Maximal ideals in $K[X_1,\dots,X_n]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284297/maximal-ideals-in-kx-1-dots-x-n).